# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Private Domains for Cloud Pages

Tags: cloudpagesurl, marketing-cloud

I have a set of Marketing Cloud Cloud Pages. We have recently purchased private domain URLs to be associated with each of the Cloud Pages. Is this possible? If so, please let me know what the procedure is.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to raise a support case to have your new Private Domain configured. 
Before doing that, however, you will need to delegate the domain to the name servers of SFMC, by creating NS records pointing to:

```
•   ns1.exacttarget.com
•   ns2.exacttarget.com
•   ns3.exacttarget.com
•   ns4.exacttarget.com
```

Once case is closed, you will be able to select this new domain when creating new Cloud Pages. Please do keep in mind, that existing Cloud Pages need to be rebuilt on this new domain, as it is not automatically updating for existing assets. You can read more about Private Domains [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318538&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1).

Comment: Also be advised that the private domains created that way by default are http:// only, so you need to purchase an SSL certificate at Salesforce for the domain to be secured like the default ones.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, a Private Domain purchase is no longer required for CloudPages custom domains - they can be provisioned through a support case at will.